# How to search for a single column when using compound indexes in IndexedDB

Tags: indexeddb

Imagine I have the following IndexedDB database with a compound index based on two fields: `["name", "surname"]`. How can I make a query to match all rows where `name=='Will'`?

ChatGPT suggests something like the following, but doesn't work (returns an empty array):

```
const getDb = async () =>
  await openDB("myDB", 1, {
    upgrade(db, _oldVersion, _newVersion, _transaction) {
      var roleStore = db.createObjectStore("myStore", {autoIncrement: true});
      roleStore.createIndex('compoundIndex', ['name', 'surname'], {
        unique: true,
      });
    },
  });

const fetchName = async(name) => {
  const db = await getDb();
  return await db
      .transaction("myStore", 'readonly')
      .objectStore("myStore")
      .index('compoundIndex')
      .getAll(IDBKeyRange.only([name, '']));
}


console.log(fetchName("Will")); // Returns empty array!
```

Is there an easy way to fetch all rows matching `name=='Will'` without actually having to fetch all values and use the JS [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function?

Comment: See description of compound indices. You can compare arrays of different lengths. Remove the second element from array value passed to IDBKeyRange.only, and since only is the implied default, just use `getAll(['name'])`

Comment: IDBKeyRange.only won't work here, since you're wanting a range from `[name, <lowest possible key>]` to `[name, <highest possible key>]`, not just records that have exactly the key `[name]`. Assuming the second key in the compound is always string, this should work: `IDBKeyRange.bound([name], [name, []])` - this is because `[name]` sorts before `[name, <anything>]` and `[name, []]` sorts after `[name, <anything>]` (where <anything> is a string or other simple key type)

Comment: @JoshuaBell your solution `IDBKeyRange.bound([name], [name, []])` works perfectly, thanks. Although doesn't seem very intuitive, for instance how could I query just the column `'surname'` using this approach? Is it recommended to include additional indexes for single columns for this kind of use cases?

Comment: @Ander Yes, using an index makes sense. - IndexedDB doesn't have very powerful query language - just keys/key ranges - and assumes you will create indexes for anything you want to make efficient queries about. That's basically where the name comes from.